# Accordion icon showing it collapsed vs. expanded is in the wrong state

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

As you can see from the image with my scrawling on it, the default state of certain accordions on this page is "expanded" or "open" upon page load. However, the little icon showing it collapsed vs. expanded is in the wrong state. How can I fix this? The icon functions and changes to show the state properly once clicked / activated, but I need the it to show if the accordion is expanded by default on page load. Using Bootstrap 4.

[image: Quick Screengrab Markup]

Tried adding aria-expanded=true inline like this:

```
<h2 class="card-title" data-toggle="tooltip" aria-expanded="true" title="Click to expand for more information">
```

but I don't think that is working because I somehow need to apply it to the button, yet the button is created on the fly by bootstrap.

```js
/** Accordions - dynamically add id **/
$.each($(".accordion"), (function(index) {
  $(this).attr("id", "accordion_" + parseInt(index + 1));
}));

/** Accordions - dynamically add interaction **/
$.each($(".accordion > .card"), (function(index, value) {
  var num = index + 1;
  $(value).children(".card-header").attr("id", "heading_acc_" + num);
  $(value).find(".card-header > .card-title").wrapInner("<button  class=\"btn btn-link\" type=\"button\" data-toggle=\"collapse\" aria-expanded=\"false\"></button>");
  $(value).find(".card-header > .card-title > button").attr({
    "data-target": "#collapse_acc_" + num,
    "aria-controls": "collapse_acc_" + num
  });
  $(value).children(".collapse").attr({
    id: "collapse_acc_" + num,
    "aria-labelledby": "heading_acc_" + num
  });
}));
```

```css
.accordion .card .card-title button::after {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5rem;
  left: 2rem;
}

.accordion .card .card-title button[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
  content: "\f107";
  color: #B9C2D0;
}

.accordion .card .card-title button[aria-expanded="false"]:after {
  content: "\f105";
  color: #B9C2D0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h2 class="card-title" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click to expand for more information">
        Accordion Title
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse collapse show">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Insert Accordion content here. And <a href="#">Aliquam erat volutpat</a>.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h2 class="card-title" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click to expand for more information">
        Accordion Title
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse collapse show">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Insert Accordion content here. And <a href="#">Aliquam erat volutpat</a>.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h2 class="card-title" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click to expand for more information">
        Accordion Title
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse collapse show">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Insert Accordion content here. And <a href="#">Aliquam erat volutpat</a>.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I'm voting to reopen, but it seems like you're trying too hard here. What's with all the custom code for the accordions? Why not just use the markup-driven approach that [Bootstrap provides](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/collapse/#accordion-example)? Then all you need is a tidy function to toggle the icon position.

Comment: I've kind of inherited someone else's code here, and I'm really a graphic designer, not a coder. So I've just been trying to do my best and work through what I can. :)

Comment: Fair enough, but we still need to know the intent behind the code you have there. I suggest opening a new question  since this one's not getting enough attention for reopen. Include the snippet from above and describe the behavior you're after in detail. Chances are we can dramatically simplify. Tag me there if you like.